# Can't return a view with include()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, razor, include

*ASP.net MVC3 Razor EF*

When I do this it works:

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Songs.Include("Artist").ToList());
    }
```

But this doesn't:

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Artists.Include("Song").ToList());
    }
```

I get this error:

**A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'MVCProject.Models.Artist' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Song'.**

Any idea why? if you need more info/code please mention which. but please let me know where something like that can happen, and how it can be solved. it's driving me crazy.

Thanks.

**Artists Class:**

```
public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistID{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Song> Songs{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It means there's not a [navigation property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738520.aspx) mapping from `Artists` to `Song`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, I can hardly understand this link tho. It's more of a document than a guide, so if you have a learning reference it would be great. tho thanks for the name, I'll search and wait for answers so it's completey ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `public IQueryable<Song> Songs{ get; set; }` with  `public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs{ get; set; }`

```
public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistID{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs{ get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
return View(db.Artists.Include("Songs").ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks, can't I use IQueryable? (because I'm using a Where() to get the Songs like this: Songs=context.Songs.Where(s => s.Artist.Name == "Artist Name")).


If I must use ICollection, how can I do this?

Comment: @Key No `IQueryable` is there to perform queries against a data source. `Songs` should be a collection which should support Add and Remove apart from querying.

Comment: Oh, so how can I manage to get all the songs that has the artists's name "X" like in the first comment?

Comment: @Ken `context.Songs` should be an `IQueryable`. But the `Songs` property in `Artist` should not.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have Songs (plural) as navigational property for Artist class. So, `return View(db.Artists.Include("Songs").ToList());` should work. If ot - you need to show Model class for Artist

Comment: Thank you for your responde. I tried to change it to "Songs", I got the same error. I have edited the question and included the Artist class. hope you could help me out with it.

Comment: you need to mark songs virtual (I assume you use code-first pattern in EF)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg715120%28v=vs.103%29.aspx